# nested recyclerview scroll indicator

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to remove the scrolling indicator that appears when you try to scroll but you are already at the start/end of the list inside a recyclerview that is nested, It should only show the indicator for the entire page, but it shows it for the recyclerview as well
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide the scrollbars of a recyclerView via

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
   ...
   android:scrollbars="none" />
```

in your layout xml file on the nested recyclerView. This will not impact the scrollability.

**EDIT:**
The indicator of the start/end of an recyclerView is called an `EdgeEffect`, assigned by an `EdgeEffectFactory`. Unfortunately you can't pass a null `EdgeEffect` neither `EdgeEffectFactory`, but you can workaround by setting the color to the background color of your list:

```
yourRecyclerView.edgeEffectFactory = object : RecyclerView.EdgeEffectFactory() {
    override fun createEdgeEffect(view: RecyclerView, direction: Int): EdgeEffect {
        val effect = EdgeEffect(context)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            effect.color = resources.getColor(R.color.your_backgrund_color, null)
        } else {
            effect.color = resources.getColor(R.color.your_backgrund_color)
        }

        return effect
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't mean the scroll bars, I meant the indicator that you've reached the top/bottom of the list. https://imgur.com/a/YU7EQQw

Comment: Ah! This wasn't clear. I will update my answer.